# A ECONNREFUSED error of the node. Js

Tags: node.js

My Node app is throwing a `ECONNREFUSED` error.  The port should not be in use.  Any ideas?

```
console.info('-----http-----');
console.info();

var http = require('http');
var options = {
    hostname: 'localhost',
    port: 6860,
    path: '/',
    method: 'post'
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    console.log('status:' + res.statusCode);

    res.setEncoding('UTF-8');
    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        console.log('body:' + chunk);
    });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('problem with request:' + e.message);
});

req.end();
```

[image]

Comment: Fixed grammar and formatted code.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are trying to send post request to one of the URL (localhost),
the code you posted that alone will not work, somewhere your server should run i.,e localhost:6860 
For that just you need to create a server which runs on the port 6860.
Execute this simple server.js file in separate terminal then run  "localhost:6860" in your browser.
Then run your code in separate terminal, it will execute properly. Check your both terminals you will get the difference.

```
**server.js**

var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    });
    console.log(req.url)
    console.log(req.method)
    res.end('okay');
}).listen(6860, "localhost");
```

> $node server.js

Hope it will help you..!